# How can I apply background on my web page using css?

Tags: html, css

I am facing problem in adding a background image using CSS. I am applying following codes for my web page design, but it's not adding image to the page and showing blank page. My html codes are running properly.

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<style>
    /* css reset  */
    body{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background: url('img\dark-1839088_1920.jpg');
    }
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<style>
    /* css reset  */
    body{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background: url('img\dark-1839088_1920.jpg');
    }
</style>
<body>
    <h1>This is heading</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as nobody will code all of this for you nor is StackOverflow a "Implement this for me" platform.

Comment: Hi, do you see any errors in your browser's dev tools console log? For example, not finding the background image because of a malformed url. Please put your code into your question then we should be able to help.

Comment: browser console is showing error - ( index.html:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
body{
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url('./img\dark-1839088_1920.jpg');
}
```